# Android -- launching app when system boot

Tags: android

hey all,
I have a app needed to be launched when system boot,
Registering a BroadcastReceiver to receive RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED Intent is a solution I have known,

but I  want to know how does the desktop app auto run from boot?
I also want to know any other means available so that I can choose a suitable one for my scenario.

any replies will be welcome.

Comment: What's wrong with the BroadcastReceiver approach?

Comment: using BroadcastReceiver is okay, but I am curious of if there is any other approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write this code in manifest file...

```
receiver android:name=".AfterBoot"

            intent-filter               
                action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" 
            intent-filter
receiver
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
```

-- AfterBoot.java file.......

```
public class AfterBoot extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           // call your app launcher activity here ....
}
}
```